# Almacenar datos en una variable para luego hacer operaciones con ellos

Tags: python

Hola recien empiezo con python y me encargaron una tarea, la cosa es hacer un login (que ya tengo ya funciona) y una caja registradora en la que se puedan poner maximo 5 articulos, el programa pregunto por:

codigo del articulo
descripcion
cantidad
precio

quieres agregar otro articulo? y/n

quisiera lograr que al final despues de capturar los 5 o menos articulos me despliegue un ticket en el que me de:

total de articulos
total (cada cantidad de cada tipo de articulos multiplicado por su respectivo precio)

y lo demas ya lo tengo solo que no lo logro ya intente con for, creando listas pero no logro almacenar los datos para luego extraerlos y hacer operaciones con ellos, ojala me puedan ayudar gracias!

```
import getpass
import time


usuarioregistrado = ("diego")
contraseñaregistrada = ("123")

def login(usuario,passw):
    if usuario in usuarioregistrado:
        if passw in contraseñaregistrada:
            return 1
        else:
            print("Contraseña incorrecta...")
    else:
        return 1
 
usuario=input("Usuario: ")
passw = getpass.getpass("Contraseña: ")
 
if login(usuario,passw)==1:
    print("Bienvenido ",usuario)
    print("           ")
    print("           ")
    print("Caja registradora")
    print("           ")

    articulo=0

    while True:
        code=input("Ingrese el codigo del producto: ")
        print("           ")
        desc=input("Ingrese una descripcion del producto: ")
        print("           ")
        cant=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad: "))
        print("           ")
        precio=int(input("Ingrese el precio del producto: "))
        print("           ")
        total = (cant*precio) 
        print("La cantidad de articulos es: ", cant)
        print("           ")
        print("El total es: ", total)
        print("           ")
        art=input("Deseas agregar otro articulo? Si/No: ")
        print("           ")
        if (art) == "no":
            break
    
    time.sleep(2)
    print("El total de articulos es: ")
    print("El total de su compra es: ")
   
else:
    print("Usuario no registrado")
```

Comment: Buen día, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que intentaste con listas. Por otra parte el `login` no funciona correctamente, si ingresas "Pedro" y cualquier contraseña lo acepta.

Comment: `if passw in contraseñaregistrada:` Significa que si escribes '1', es una contraseña válida, pues '1' está en '123'.

Comment: `contraseñaregistrada = ("123")` no es una lista, sino una cadena.

Comment: `def login(usuario,passw):` siempre retorna de inmediato, sin importar lo que el usuario escriba.

Comment: `return 1` . Estás en Python, no en lenguajes primitivos. Usa `return True` (o `return False`).

Comment: @CandidMoe okay dejame intentar cambiar eso recien paso de pseudocodigo a python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te comparto el código que puede hacer lo que necesitas, me tomé la libertad de modificar un poco.

Espero que sea entendible:

- Quité el último else porqué podía acceder aunque pusiera mal el usuario y contraseña.
- "\n" esto nos indica un salto de línea.
- Hace falta agregar una lista (vector, arreglo) para cada una de las informaciones que quieres ir almacenando (precio, descripción, etc.).
- Para agregar información a cada lista necesitas escribir el nombre de la lista mas ".append".
- Por último se utiliza el For para poder imprimir lo que hay dentro de cada lista.

  import getpass
  import time

  usuarioregistrado = "diego"
  contraseñaregistrada = "123"

  def login(usuario,passw):
  if usuario in usuarioregistrado:
  if passw in contraseñaregistrada:
  return 1
  else:
  print("Contraseña incorrecta...")

  usuario = input("Usuario: ")
  passw = getpass.getpass("Contraseña: ")

  if login(usuario,passw)==1:
  print("Bienvenido ",usuario)
  print("\n") #\n es brinco de línea
  print("Caja registradora")

  ```
   codigos = [] #Se crea el vector o lista
   descripciones = [] #Se crea el vector o lista
   cantidades = [] #Se crea el vector o lista
   precios = [] #Se crea el vector o lista
   totales = [] #Se crea el vector o lista

   while True:
       code=input("\nIngrese el codigo del producto: ")
       codigos.append(code) #Se añaden los códigos al vector
       desc=input("\nIngrese una descripcion del producto: ")
       descripciones.append(desc) #Se añaden las descripciones al vector
       cant=int(input("\nIngrese la cantidad: "))
       cantidades.append(cant) #Se añaden las cantidades al vector
       precio=int(input("\nIngrese el precio del producto: "))
       precios.append(precio) #Se añaden los precios al vector

       total = (cant*precio)
       totales.append(total)

       art=input("\nDeseas agregar otro articulo? Si/No: ")

       if (art) == "no":
           break

   print("Generando ticket...\n")
   time.sleep(2)

   total = 0

   for i in range(len(codigos)): #Con el For puedes imprimir lo que hay en los vectores y usas "len" para saber el tamaño.
       print(str(codigos[i]), str(descripciones[i]), str(cantidades[i]), "$", str(precios[i]), "$", str(totales[i]))

       total = total + totales[i]

   total = str(total)

   print("\nSu total a pagar es: $", total)
  ```

  else:
  print("Usuario no registrado")

Comment: Se agradece el esfuerzo. El OP debe editar su pregunta con tus cambios, si está de acuerdo. Pero, como no es realmente una respuesta, probablemente sea eliminada tras un tiempo.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muchas gracias bro es justo lo que estaba buscando voy a estudiar esa parte que agregaste porque me sirve para otras cosas que voy a hacer, gracias!